# "Righello" oppure "riga graduata"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

A volte succede che mi manca il vocabolario adeguato per esprimere i fatti della vita quotidiana. Qual è il vocabolo più usuale per chiamare lo strumento della  fotografia? Ho trovato "righello", ma anche "riga graduata" su [Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riga_(strumento)). Anche l'immagine è tratta da Wikipedia.

[image]

Comment: ***Righello vs riga graduata:*** https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=riga+graduata%2Crighello&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Criga%20graduata%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crighello%3B%2Cc0. Direi che righello è la definizione che tutti capiscono. Forse nelle scuole tecniche (geometri, periti etc.) usano il termine *riga graduata*. Se  mi chiedessero una 'riga graduata' chiederei cos'è.

Comment: Stai attenta a distinguere il righello dallo scalimetro.

Comment: L'articolo di Wikipedia, nonostante sia intitolato _Riga (strumento)_, non parla delle righe non graduate, utilizzate da artigiani, lavoratori edili, artisti, ecc.

Comment: Io in genere utilizzo il termine *righello* per uno strumento più corto di una *riga*. Nel caso specifico, quello nell'immagine è lungo 30 centimetri e secondo me è un righello. Da circa mezzo metro in poi parlerei di riga.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Io non direi altro che “righello”. “Riga graduata”, per quanto corretto e chiaro, è un'espressione più formale, che penserei di trovare semmai su un catalogo o un testo di legge; o in un testo di matematica, ma solo se strettamente necessario (per esempio per specificare che le classiche costruzioni geometriche con riga e compasso contemplano una riga *non* graduata).

Comment: Aggiungerei che è abbastanza comune chiamare il _righello_ semplicemente _riga_, anche se la riga può essere graduata o meno, mentre il righello è (credo) sempre graduato.